# How to reuse pyproject.toml in monorepo with Poetry?

Tags: python, monorepo, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

There are multiple projects in my monorepo, which has package management via Poetry individually. For instance,

```
monorepo
├── a
│   └── pyproject.toml
├── b
│   └── pyproject.toml
└── c
    └── pyproject.toml
```

Each project has its **own** sessions for `[tool.poetry.dependencies]` and `[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]`. However, they did share huge amount of common configs such as

- [tool.taskipy.tasks]
- [tool.isort]
- [tool.black]
- ...

My question is how to define common configs which could be reused for monorepo projects?

Answer (score 1):

You could go with

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
rootproject = {path = "path/to/root/project"}
```

However keep in mind that each dependency will still have its' own Virtual Environment, if that's not sufficient you can go with a different tool such as pip-tools.

Answer (score 0):

See this discussion _https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2270

> You can do that by creating a local config (poetry.toml) for each of your sub-packages with virtualenvs.create false. You then mark the sub-packages as dependencies as suggested by @fredrikaverpil and include them as packages.

Comment: Will the main *pyproject.toml* pull the dependencies of the sub-projects in its main virtual env on `poetry install`?